# Google Play Games Services anti-piracy feature delays activity creation

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm developing a multiplayer game on Android using Google Play Games Services for realtime multiplayer and leaderboards. I activated the anti-piracy functionality in the developer console and it seems that the [associated license check](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/antipiracy#how_the_anti-piracy_feature_works) is run first thing on application start before `onCreate()` is called in my toplevel splash screen activity (logcat shows `I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487` before my log message in `onCreate()` and it doesn't show up at all when anti-piracy functionality is disabled).
That means the splash screen is empty during the license check and only gets populated with its layout afterwards, which looks bad. Is there some way I can get my activity to be layed out before that license check starts or make it run concurrently?